# Changing body bgcolor inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the Body bgcolor inside iframe. This is my iframe

```
  console.log(iframe)
```

[image]

I used this code

```
$(iframe.id).contents().find('body').css({'background-color' : 'transparent'});
```

it is adding transparent inside the style but i want to change bgcolor:#ffffff to transparent. See the attached image below.

[image: image2]

Comment: can you provide a demo?

Comment: what do you mean by demo? Can you see the image attached in my post? I can access the iframe but how can i access the body inside the iframe so that i can change the bgcolor

Comment: try with `$(iframe)[0].contentWindow.$("body").css('background-color','transparent') `

Comment: Assuming the iframe is on the same domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just doing this :

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body').css({'background-color' : 'transparent'});
```

If it doesn't work, try that :

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body').css({'background-color' : 'inherit'});
```

`$('iframe').contents()` gets the content of the iframe, then you can change the backgroud of the `body`

**EDIT :**

So, following the comments, to remove the `bgcolor` attribute and add the `transparent` background, do that :

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body').css({'background-color' : 'transparent'}).removeAttr('bgcolor');
```

Comment: i get undefined value

Comment: @OwaisAhmed : The domain into the iframe must to be inside your network. With the security policy, any browser blocks any script trying to access a frame that has another origin

Comment: yes it is on the same domain. When i am doing console.log(iframe) then i can see the iframe with the html and body loaded but when i am trying the code you provided i get undefined. @Zl3n

Comment: @OwaisAhmed Just tested in my local network and it works.

Comment: ok i am able to add transparent using this code $(iframe.id).contents().find('body').css({'background-color' : 'transparent'});. But the transparent value has been added into the style and bgcolor="#ffffff" is still there. Can you check my updated question i have attached the screen shot

Comment: i have also updated the code. $(iframe.id).contents().find('body').css({'background-color' : 'transparent'});

Comment: Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/yrC2E/4/ the only difference is that I am caching the iframe contents in a variable, which is easier to manipulate later. (unfortunately the background gets changed after window load but you can see it turn red initially). You need to use quote marks for your selector if you are targetting a DOM element. So $('iframe'); I use var iframeContents = $('iframe').contents(); then I can manipulate that instance using $(iframeContents).css('change some css etc');